# Export files from Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

I currently have an Xcode workspace with an app project and the pod project (as commonly happens). I would like to "export" some of the files containing classes and structs that would be preparatory for a new project that should begin soon. These files are totally separate from each other and should not be exported as a library or framework because that should require to keep everything updated. Instead, I would rather bring these files out of the app project, but keep them into the workspace. Is it possibile? If so, how can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to keep your common code and be able to maintain it as one code on both projects then I suggest you still use a framework. It is hard to tell from your question what you mean by "because that should require to keep everything updated" but using a framework within your workspace works awesomely in Xcode and any change you do within framework is instantly reflected in your code. So no extra  deployment work is needed at all. To do so you simply do the following:

1. Create a new project selecting Framework
2. When creating the project select your workspace from dropdown menu (it is at step where you select project folder location)
3. In Xcode file navigator in newly created framework project open "Products" directory which should contain (in red) `FrameworkName.framework`
4. Open your main project target settings and open *General*, scroll down to *Frameworks, Libraries...* and drag that .framework file in this list

That is all. Now you can use your framework in your code. Simply import it in any Swift file you want to.

If at this point you are worried that you need to add `import MyFramework` into each and every Swift file where you use it then there is a shortcut. You can simply add a new Swift file and use type aliases to avoid this problem:

```
import MyFramework

typealias Class1 = MyFramework.Class1
typealias Class2 = MyFramework.Class2
typealias Class3 = MyFramework.Class3
```

Not the cleanest solution but it does the job.

On the other hand if you wish to extract files and use them in a new project but not share the code. So then each of the projects may eventually end up with different implementations of these files then you need to duplicate the files. You can do that easiest with file system by copying source files themselves.

You can then put them into workspace under whatever you want. If you wish that currently none of the projects contain these files you may simply select files in Xcode and uncheck *Target Membership* for all projects on file settings.